# How to access current user in tastypie patch request

Tags: tastypie

I'm attempting to post multiple objects using a PATCH request, but I get this error:
`"error_message": "'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'user'"`

My resource model is as follows:

```
class TrackerResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Tracker.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'tracker'
        allowed_methods = ['post','patch','put']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['post','patch','put']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization() 
        always_return_data =  True
        fields = ['data','tracker_date','badges','module','completed']


    def hydrate(self, bundle, request=None):
        bundle.obj.user = bundle.request.user
        bundle.obj.ip = bundle.request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR','0.0.0.0')
        bundle.obj.agent = bundle.request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT','unknown')
        return bundle
```

And the curl request I'm making is (with the proper api_key):

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH --data '{"objects":[{"digest":"e5b24a362259b1408161829737f8ef3c","data":"{}","completed":1},{"digest":"e5b24a362259b1408161829737f8ef3c","data":"{}","completed":0}]}' "http://localhost/python/modules/api/v1/tracker/?username=alex&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

It works fine if I only POST a single object with:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"digest":"e5b24a362259b1408161829737f8ef3c","data":"{}","completed":0}' "http://localhost/python/modules/api/v1/tracker/?username=alex&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

So, when I make a PATCH request, what's the right way to be able to access the current user object? Or do I need to do something to make the PATCH request send the current request to each hydrate method?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've got it working now, needed to add a patch_list method to my TrackerResource:

```
def patch_list(self,request,**kwargs):
    request = convert_post_to_patch(request)
    deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
    for data in deserialized["objects"]:
        data = self.alter_deserialized_detail_data(request, data)
        bundle = self.build_bundle(data=dict_strip_unicode_keys(data))
        bundle.request.user = request.user
        self.obj_create(bundle, request=request)
    return http.HttpAccepted()
```

Not sure if this is really the best way to handle it, but is working for me.